# Jpa inheritance joined strategy mapping issue

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

hi everyone I am trying to use JPA inheritance as follow:
`

```
@Entity(name = "request_type")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)

// request type
public class RequestType {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
....
}

// expense type extends request type
@Entity
@Table(name = "expense_type")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public class ExpenseType extends RequestType implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "code", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer code;

}


// I need to map type field to Expense type

@Entity
@Table(name = "expense")
public class Expense extends Request implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    private ExpenseType type;

}
```

When I try to retrieve expense list using find all I got this error:
Unknown column 'expense0_.type_parent_id' in 'field list'.
Please any one can help me fixing this

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I found the issue, I need to specify the join column

```
 @ManyToOne(optional = false) 
 @JoinColumn(name ="type_id")
@NotNull
private ExpenseType type;
```